# Why does logging.setLevel() has no effect here with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I try to understand how the `logging` module really works. The following code doesn't react like I expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging

l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print('enabled for DEBUG: {}'.format(l.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)))

l.debug('debug')
l.info('info')
l.warning('warning')
l.error('error')
l.critical('critical')
```

It just print out this to the console.

```
warning
error
critical
```

But why? Shouldn't there be `info` and `debug`, too? Why not?

The question is not how to fix this. I know about handlers and things like that. I just try to understand how this code work and why it doesn't react like I expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When no handler is set, the `lastResort` handler is used, and by default the `lastResort` level is set to `WARNING`.

This is implemented by [this bit of code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1492):

```
_defaultLastResort = _StderrHandler(WARNING)
lastResort = _defaultLastResort

    def callHandlers(self, record):
        ...
        found = 0
        ...
        if (found == 0):
            if lastResort:
                if record.levelno >= lastResort.level:
                    lastResort.handle(record)
```

Remember also that [both loggers and handlers have levels](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-levels). A record can be
filtered by the logger for having too low a level, and it can also be filtered
by a handler for having too low a level. Setting the logger level to DEBUG allows the subsequent logging calls to pass the logger's level filter, but they [can still be filtered](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) by the handler's level filter, which is set to `lastResort.level`, i.e. `WARNING`, by default.